# How to setup a RS-232 Cape for BeagleBone Black

Tags: rs232, beaglebone-black

I'm trying to use a RS-232 cape in a python script. A TU-S9 USB-to-Serial converter works just fine with same code I just change the port. So I don't think it is my code. The only thing I can think of is that I am missing something setup wise. The Cape doesn't come with any documentation (that I have found). I've tried UART 1,2,4 same result. the port will open but it never gets a response from the device. The device is a DirectLogic 05 PLC. I'm using ModBus RTU.

Edit: from what I can tell the UART ports for the beaglebone are listed as /dev/ttyO0, /dev/ttyO1,/dev/ttyO2,/dev/ttyO3,/dev/ttyO4. /dev/ttyO0 is used by the OS though.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote saying this is off-topic because it is a question about the use of an electronic device.  Rather, this is about the firmware programming of a peripheral for an embedded system, which is certainly on-topic on this site.  If you went by this person's logic, then practically every firmware question on this site would be off-topic.

Comment: If someone would like to susgest a better SE site for this im all ears. But this doesnt fit any stack exchange site well.

Comment: No, just stay here, you're fine.  We have lots of BeagleBone Black questions here already as you can see from the RELATED column to the right.  I've got a BBB myself; sorry I can't help you out on this question.

Comment: Can you probe the signals on the board with a scope? See which UARTs you have available? The UARTs should also show up in the /dev directory, probably named /dev/ttyACMxx (ACM may vary) or similar. That way you can investigate which ports you have available.

Comment: It's not a great SE question.  The right place would be the support site for the RS232 cape.

Answer (score 1):

Using the version 3.8 or higher of the Linux Kernel, you can set a [Device Tree Overlay](http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_and_the_3.8_Kernel).

By this method, at runtime, you can incorporate the system device drivers.

Personally, I implemented the necessary hardware to operate with a RS-485 interface and Modbus protocol. This basically is the hardware for Bus transceiver and its associated components. When I wanted to start the operation, I could see that the ttyO4 port was not enabled.
I found the solution [here](http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-serialuarttty-on-beaglebone-black/), where the code is presented to compile an Overlay to enable the port ttyO4. Once implemented this, everything worked properly.

**Attention**

In Beaglebone board I used, the operating system installed was **Ubuntu**. When compiling the file with the Overlay, compilation tool threw an error concerning did *not recognize the option "@"*. This is solved, and [here's](http://www.embedded-things.com/bbb/patching-the-device-tree-compiler-for-ubuntu/) how to apply the patch for the Overlay compiler. Therefore, I recommend the Overlay compiler what you obtain source code instead of using a repository.